# UIView animationWithDuration duration set not being acknowledged

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I've implemented the animationWithDuration code block in my project about 5 times, but when I try to create a new class and put any kind of animation in viewDidLoad, the animation doesn't honor the duration I set it too. For example, I put in a duration of 5.0, the animation doesn't care and still animates it at 0.5 seconds. When I create a new project and copy the exact piece of code into it, it works perfectly fine and does animate for 5 seconds. Here's the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 5
                      delay: 0.2
                    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |  UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse)
                 animations:^{
                     water.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);
                 } completion:nil];
```

**edit**: A colleague told me to try putting it in `viewDidAppear` and that works. But I still want to know why, in the 5 previous ViewControllers before this specific one, all the animations work when placed in viewDidLoad. My guess is that maybe for some reason, loading the graphics in this specific ViewController takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in `viewDidAppear:` because you only want your animation to start when it is visible.

Comment: That worked. Any idea why it works in viewDidLoad for the other classes but not when I make a new class?

Comment: Maybe your subclass has some additional computation between the view loading (`viewDidLoad`) and the view appearing (`viewDidAppear:`). The correct place would be `viewDidAppear:` for the reason I stated in my answer